# Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin: declarative pipeline and pod template inheritance

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

The documentation of the Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin states:

> Unlike scripted k8s template, declarative templates do not inherit from parent template. You need to explicitly declare the inheritance if necessary.
>   [Plugin Readme](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#default-inheritance)

Unfortunately there is no example of how to explicitly state the inheritance from the build's main template. I tried using the label, but then the inheritance seems to be ignored.

```
def parentLabel = "my-project-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"

pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            label parentLabel
            yamlFile "jenkins-agent.yml"
            // a global template in the cloud configuration
            inheritFrom "docker"
        }
    }
    stages {
        // .. stages using the above agent
        stage( 'Test Container' ) {
            agent {
                kubernetes {
                    label "xcel-spring-stage-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"
                    inheritFrom parentLabel
                    yaml """
                    apiVersion: v1
                    kind: Pod
                    metadata:
                      namespace: build
                      labels:
                        project: x-celerate-spring-application
                    spec:
                      containers:
                        - name: spring-application
                          # defined in previous stages, skipped for brevity
                          image: ${env.IMAGE_NAME}:${version}.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}
                    """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How / by what template name can I reference the template declared at the top of the pipeline in an `inheritFrom` statement in the stage agent declaration to actually define the inheritance explicitly?

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this?

Comment: Not really, we just fully define the stage agent templates, without any inheritance

Comment: Yup that's the solution I came up with as well. What a shame. Appreciate the response though.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#default-inheritance) about default inheritance has been updated, it states now:

> You need to explicitly declare the inheritance if necessary **using the field inheritFrom**.

There is two examples in the documentation:

```
podTemplate(inheritFrom: 'mypod', containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'maven', image: 'maven:3.8.1-jdk-11')
  ]) {
  node(POD_LABEL) {
    …
  }
}
```

or in declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      inheritFrom 'mypod'
      yaml '''
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: maven
          image: maven:3.8.1-jdk-11
'''
      …
    }
  }
  stages {
    …
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question: in a stage agent, what is the correct value for `inheritFrom` to reference the top-level pipeline agent pod template.